# Script is working, but only with a "hack"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

**Background:**

I am part of a large family and to save everyone some money at Christmas, we do a Secret Santa of sorts for gift giving.  I am writing this script so that this all can be managed via a spreadsheet since our process can be somewhat messy.  The rules are:

1. Each "Santa" is given two names that they must buy gifts for.
2. Those 2 names can not be the same.
3. Couples can not give gifts to each other or their children. Children
   can not give gifts to their siblings or their parents.

Here is a table with some example data:
[image: sample data]

**The Problem**

I believe my issue is occurring because of the following code:

```
//Remove disallowedNames from currentAvailableNames
for (j=0; j<disallowed.length; j++){
  var disallowedName = disallowed[j];
  currentAvailableNames.splice(currentAvailableNames.indexOf(disallowed[j]), 1);
}
```

For some reason, the disallowed name(s) are also being removed from the availableNames array and I have no idea why.  The only way I have been able to "fix" it, is by adding in the following code after the recipient has been picked:

```
//Add Disallowed Names back to Available Names Array
for (k=0; k<disallowed.length; k++){
  var disallowedName = disallowed[k];
  if (disallowedName.length >0) {
    availableNames.push(disallowedName);
  }
}
```

**Original Code**

```
function giftAssignments() {
  //Get Settings
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var settings = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
  var resultsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Results");
  var numOfAssignments = settings.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var minPrice = settings.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var maxPrice = settings.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var firstName = settings.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var santasLastRow = settings.getLastRow();
  var santasLastCol = settings.getLastColumn();
  var santasTotal = santasLastRow - firstName + 1;
  var santasAsRange = settings.getRange(firstName,1,(santasLastRow - firstName + 1), santasLastCol).getValues();

  //Create Santas Array (santas)
  var santas = []
  for (var i=0; i<santasAsRange.length; i++) {
    var name = santasAsRange[i][0];
    var email = santasAsRange[i][1];
    var disallowedAsString = santasAsRange[i][2];
    disallowedAsString = disallowedAsString.replace(", ",",");
    var disallowed =  disallowedAsString.split(",");
    disallowed.push(name);
    var santa = [];
    santa[0] = name;
    santa[1] = email;
    santa[2] = disallowed;
    santas.push(santa);
  }
  //Create Array of Names (availableNames)
  var availableNames = [];
  for (i=0; i<santas.length; i++) {
    var aName = santas[i][0];
    availableNames.push(aName);
  }
  //Assign Recipients
  var results = assignRecip(santas, availableNames);
  Logger.log("RESULTS = " + results);
}


function assignRecip(santas, names) {
  var availableNames = names;
  for (i=0; i<santas.length; i++) {
    var currentAvailableNames = availableNames;
    var name = santas[i][0];
    var disallowed = santas[i][2];
    Logger.log("Santa = " + name);
    Logger.log("availableNames = " + availableNames);

    //Remove disallowedNames from currentAvailableNames
    for (j=0; j<disallowed.length; j++){
      var disallowedName = disallowed[j];
      currentAvailableNames.splice(currentAvailableNames.indexOf(disallowed[j]), 1);
    }
    Logger.log("currentAvailableNames = " + currentAvailableNames);

    //Pick Random Ricipient from currentAvailableNames
    var recipient = currentAvailableNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * currentAvailableNames.length)];
    Logger.log("Recipient = " + recipient); 

    //Add Recipient to Santa Array
    santas[i].push(recipient);

    //Add Disallowed Names back to Available Names Array
    for (k=0; k<disallowed.length; k++){
      var disallowedName = disallowed[k];
      if (disallowedName.length >0) {
        availableNames.push(disallowedName);
      }
    }

    //Add Recipient to Disallowed Names Array
    santas[i][2].push(recipient);

    //Remove Recipient from Available Names Array
    availableNames.splice(availableNames.indexOf(recipient),1);
    Logger.log("availableNames = " + availableNames);
    Logger.log(" ");
  }
  return santas;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're references to the same Array. This code doesn't copy the Array itself. It copies the reference to the Array.

```
var currentAvailableNames = availableNames;
```

You can fix it using `.slice()`.

```
var currentAvailableNames = availableNames.slice();
```

Now you have two separate Arrays, so direct modifications to `currentAvailableNames` will not affect `availableNames`.

Note that this is a shallow clone. If it was an Array of Objects or Arrays, then modifications to the nested Object would still be visible from both Arrays.

Comment: Wow.  That explains a lot. Thanks!